# How to read a program memory range with pk3cmd

Tags: microchip

I need to read a ** program memory range** in a microchip microcontroller using the command line pk3cmd.exe, but I have errors or pk3cmd read all memory program.

### I have used the next arguments:

**PK3CMD -P32MX440F512H -GPFC:\DemoCode.Hex -N1d000000,1d0000FF -V3.3**

> Result: Incorrect number format for radix 10

**PK3CMD -P32MX440F512H -GPFC:\DemoCode.Hex -N0x1d000000,0x1d0000ff -V3.3**

> Result: Value must have a value 0x200*n - 1. Example: 0x1ff

**PK3CMD -P32MX440F512H -GPFC:\DemoCode.Hex -N486539264,256 -V3.3**

> Result: Value not in range [0x1d000000, 0x1d07ffff]

**PK3CMD -P32MX440F512H -GPFC:\DemoCode.Hex -N486539264,486539519 -V3.3**

> Result: Value must have a value 0x200*n - 1. Example: 0x1ff

**PK3CMD -P32MX440F512H -GPFC:\DemoCode.Hex -N0x1d000000,0x100 -V3.3**

> Result: Value not in range [0x1d000000, 0x1d07ffff]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I did it. After many attempts, I decided to disassemble the jar files of MPLAB IPE, and I found the solution reading the java code.

```
PK3CMD -P32MX440F512H -GP1d000000-1d0000ff -V3.3
```

The response is sent to the screen, but you can redirect the standard output to a file.